# Are the contents of chests in battles random?

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend

When battling enemy troops in King's Bounty: The Legend, the battlefield will often contain one or more chests.

I make it a point to open a fair share of these chests, which vary in contents from a negligable amount of gold to the extremely useful Might/Mind/Magic runes.

So I was wondering - are the contents of the chests pre-determined (and if so, are the chest placements throughout battles pre-determined as well)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember my discussions from the [forum](http://forum.1cpublishing.eu/forumdisplay.php?f=180) correctly, then the contents of chests are random. You can get more information from the forum.

Comment: It would have been nicer if I didn't have to dig for it myself, but I did find http://forum.1cpublishing.eu/showpost.php?p=126406&postcount=3, so thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! You did a good job of finding that post (I didn't remember the exact details, and I thought I answered your question, so I didn't bother). Maybe you should post the stats from the post here as an answer for future seekers?